# How to use If,else in form_for helper to extract specific field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have following code in my edit view:

```
<%= form_for @content do |f|%>
  <% if f.text_field :home %>
    <%= f.label :Home %>
    <%= f.text_field :home %>
  <% elsif f.text_field :aboutus %>
  <%= f.label :Abouts %>
  <%= f.text_field :aboutus %>
 <% end %>
<%= f.submit%>
```

Here @content contain following information:

```
id: "1", home: "staticcontent", aboutus: "staticcontent"
```

so i wants that if someone wants to edit home page he can see only home submission form and if he choose aboutus, he can see edit form page for only about us.suggest me whats correct way to use if,else in this block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a URL param and work with that. For example:

```
# in some view
<%= link_to "Edit Homepage", edit_content_path(page: "home")
# this will link to /contents/:id/edit?page=home
```

Then in your form:

```
<%= form_for @content do |f|%>
  <% if params[:page] == "home" %>
    <%= f.label :home %>
    <%= f.text_field :home %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.label :about_us %>
    <%= f.text_field :about_us %>
 <% end %>
<%= f.submit%>
```

Notice I downcased the labels, and changed `aboutus` to `about_us` so that the label displays correctly.

Comment: what changes should i do in routes for this edit_content_path(page: "home") ?

Comment: Nothing, just use the current URL helper for the edit page. You can pass whatever params you want to the URL helper, even ones you don't use, for example: `edit_content_path(page: "foo", blabla: "hi")` will create `/contents/:id/edit?page=foo&blabla=hi`

Comment: i got following error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"contents", :page=>"home"}